# Bar plot in ggplot2 with ordered bars and manually specified colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to generate a simple bar plot with ggplot2 with the bars ordered by the y-value and the colours manually defined. Here is what I tried:

```
df <- data.frame(c("a", "b", "c"), c(2, 3, 1))
colnames(df) <- c("shop", "revenue")
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(shop, revenue), y = revenue, fill = shop)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "yellow", "black")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: The colours are wrongly ordered.]

The problem is: the colours are wrongly ordered (black, blue and yellow instead of blue, yellow and black as stated in `scale_fill_manual`). How to fix this?

Comment: You can manually map the colors to specific values in scale_fill_manual like so: scale_fill_manual(values = c("c" = "blue", "a" = "yellow", "b" = "black")).

Comment: Try `scale_fill_manual(values = setNames(c("blue", "yellow", "black"), 
                                      df$shop[order(df$revenue)]))`

Comment: Reorder `fill` as well as `x`

Comment: @Richard, Jeroen: both your suggestions work, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `scale_fill_manual` you assign colors to levels in your data.
At the same time, you use `reorder(shop, revenue)` in the definition of `aes`, which orders the data from left to right in ascending order. The third and last definition of the color "blue" was assigned to **c** which is now at the left hand side as it is the smallest.

You could time this to circumvent this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(shop, revenue), y = revenue, fill = shop)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "black", "blue")) +  # CHANGED
  theme_minimal()
```

Or as @JeroenBoeye suggested:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(shop, revenue), y = revenue, fill = shop)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("c" = "blue", "a" = "yellow", "b" = "black")) + # Jeroen Boeye's suggestion
  theme_minimal()
```

Please let me know whether this solves your problem.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. It's pretty obvious that you can manually rearrange the colors. The deeper question is how do you assign colors *after* reordering.

Comment: @PierreLafortune You are right. In that light, Jeroen Boeye suggestion is a better solution.

Comment: I think both these solutions may be missing something - if the colours are intrinsically assigned to the values of `shop` then they need to be assigned in the plot with those values, however shop is ordered.  Thus if shop `a` is always yellow, the question is more how to keep that connection between the colour and the values of shop.